# How to remove multiple email on git?

Tags: git, github

I keep getting this error on my git

> warning: user.email has multiple values

then i check my user.mail

```
git config --get-all user.mail
juanlazy21@gmail.com
juanlazy21@gmail.com
juanlazy21@gmail.com
```

I also check

```
git config -e
```

and this is the file :

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/cloudy/coding.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "resolutions"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/resolutions
```

and i dont have any repository on my local environment . I only have one.

Comment: `git config --global --edit`

Answer (score 2):

You can (instead of manually edit) remove them with:

```
 git config --global --unset user.mail
 git config --global --unset user.mail
```

That will removes the first two entries of `user.mail`.

Then check for any extra emails in:

```
git config --get-all user.email           # (local repo git config file)
git config --global --get-all user.email  # (user config file)
git config --system --get-all user.email  # (system git config file)
```